# How does CLOCK_MONOTONIC handle NTP changes to the system clock?

Tags: c, linux, system-clock

Savvy engineers use `clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &my_timspec_struct )` to get a continuously increasing epoch-style clock that is "unaffected" by changes to the system clock. (Where the epoch-start is not defined).

However, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` *is* effected by NTP daemon time-changes known as clock "slewing".

By the definition of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, we know that it will never jump backwards.  But how does it it mitigate changes by NTP?   If the system-clock is suddenly set 5 hours in the past by NTP, does the monotonic clock run a bit slower until it catches up?  Maybe it just stops "ticking" until the difference evens-out?

What really does happen? If it's system dependent, what happens on Linux?

I have some timing related code that's failing where the hardware clocks are very flaky.  They're being re-adjusted to a GPS source every few minutes.  And while this reads like it *shouldn't* effect `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, sometimes (1 in 20) timing related code is just not working. I can't just change everything to `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`, because libraries (e.g.: Qt) still use non-raw (Ref: Qt 5.15 source).

Comment: That the hardware clocks are flaky suggests that the system's clock *source(s)* may be unreliable.  Perhaps it stalls from time to time, or doesn't reliably produce the required voltage levels.  I would expect such effects to impact `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and probably `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`, too.  They shouldn't move backwards, but they might stop moving *forwards* for a time, or they might advance at inconsistent speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What really does happen? If it's system dependent, what happens on Linux?

It is system-dependent whether there even is a `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.  The only clock that POSIX requires implementations to provide is `CLOCK_REALTIME`.  So, what happens on Linux?

[The docs](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime) have this to say about `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`:

> Clock that cannot be set and represents monotonic time since some
> unspecified starting point. This clock is not affected by
> discontinuous jumps in the system time (e.g., if the system
> administrator manually changes the clock), but is affected by the
> incremental adjustments performed by `adjtime`(3) and NTP.

[The docs for `adjtime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/adjtime) add:

> If the adjustment in *delta* is positive, then the system clock is
> speeded up by some small percentage (i.e., by adding a small amount of
> time to the clock value in each second) until the adjustment has been
> completed. If the adjustment in *delta* is negative, then the clock is
> slowed down in a similar fashion.

From that we can conclude that `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` moves at the same speed as the system clock, which is why it is affected when NTP slews the clock or `adjtime()` is used, but that it is not updated when the system clock is set.  It just keeps counting up, monotonically.

Comment: Note also that as far as I am aware, the unspecified starting point for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` time is not required to remain the same across reboots.